# Magento 2.2.1 404 not found error when switch store on product detail page

Tags: magento2.2, store-view, product-view, 404-page, multiple

I am working on **Magento 2.2.1** and I have configured multiple store view **Hungarian** and **Romanian**.

When I switch store from **Hungarian** to **Romanian** on **product detail** page I am getting 404 not found error.

Can anyone tell me how can I resolve this?

My website url 
http://storyprint.ro/ro/ftshirt.html

Comment: Anything in console of browser or Magento logs? Reindex is working?

Comment: Nothing found in magento logs reindex also not working

Comment: How did you setuped versions?

Comment: You are taking about magento version?

Comment: One thing I want to confirm is  issue in magneto 2.2.1 framework or not?

Comment: I don't think so, Its difficult to help without any details.

Comment: This is my website url http://storyprint.ro/ro/ftshirt.html

Comment: Make sure the product is enabled, assigned to the website and is in stock for the store you are checking.

Comment: Yes I have checked the product is enable in that store view and is in stock in main website I have develop three store view english Hungarian and Romanian. I have check in url_rewrite table when I create new product from admin that only created url for default english store.other store view url is not created in table.

Comment: I checked on my side is working.

Comment: Where you check